# Callable cloud function is not running and throwing error when called

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to do a Cloud Function that calls a request to the url passed to it. I have never used typescript to make a request, so I added some print calls in order to see if the axios could be the issue but the first log never appears in the Cloud Console. So I have no idea what is wrong and need some help. Can you please tell me why is my function not working, or not running at all?

Cloud Function [Typescript]

```
export const requestFromServer = functions.https.onCall(async (data)=> {
  console.log("to create axios");
  // try {
  console.log("entering try/catch block");
  const response = await axios.default.get(data as string);
  console.log("response about to be returned");
  console.log(response);
  return response;
  // } catch (e) {
  //   console.log("error:");
  //   console.log(e);
  //   return null;
  // }
});
```

I tried both with the commented code and without. All I need is a cloud function that will make a request regardless of it using Axios or not.

Cloud Console log

```
requestFromServer
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"bryancoellobusiness@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/shipping0110/locations/us-central1/functions/requestFromServer"}
```

Calling cloud function in app [Dart]

```
class CloudFunctions {
  static final _functions = FirebaseFunctions.instance;

  Future requestFromServer(String url) async {
    print('hey I was called');
    try {
      var response =
          await _functions.httpsCallable('requestFromServer').call(url);
      print('comessss back');
      print('response.data: ${response}');
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString()); //error message below
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Console Error in VSCode

```
[firebase_functions/internal] internal
Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'data'
method not found
Reciever: null
Arguments: []
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:5069:11)
    at Object.defaultNoSuchMethod (http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:5503:15)
    at Object.noSuchMethod (http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:5499:27)
    at Object.dload (http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:5130:17)
at places_service.PlacesService.new.getAutoComplete (http://localhost:51782/packages/app/services/places_service.dart.lib.js:104:58)
    at getAutoComplete.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:40578:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:40448:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:35370:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:35938:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:35976:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeError] (http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:35830:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:35866:31)
hey I was called
[firebase_functions/internal] internal
Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'data'
method not found
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:40715:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:40721:13)
    at http://localhost:51782/dart_sdk.js:36198:9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was I imported all of the stuff in Axios instead of only importing axios

```
import * as axios from "axios"; //before
import axios from "axios";

export const serverRequest = functions.https.onCall(async (url, context)=> {
  isAuthenticatedAdmin(context);
  const response = await axios.get(url as string).then(({data})=> data);
  return response;
});
```

Comment: You can write cloud functions in Typescript. I find it very helpful when combined with VS Code.